# Google Cloud PHP CORS issue

Tags: php, google-cloud-functions, cors

I have migrated a PHP api to google cloud functions using the PHP (beta) language. The code requests data from an external application which is returned in an XML format and then the API gets the results and outputs them as JSON for the angular app to read

My code works when using POSTMAN (so I know it returns the correct data) but when running from my Angular app either locally or hosted on google firebase I get the below CORS issue

```
Request URL: [[google firebase cloud function url]]
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 500
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/moca-xml
Referrer: http://localhost:4200/
Response-Encoder: application/xml
Response-Type: text
```

```
Request Payload:
[[Data sent to external app to request data ]]
```

The original PHP API used got around CORS by setting headers:

```
//set header of return output
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Response-Encoder, Response-Type');  
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

In the google firebase cloud function, both using the above or the suggested below method have no effect and result in the CORS errors

```
$headers = ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'];
$headers = array_merge($headers, [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Origin, Content-Type, Response-Encoder, Response-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '1000',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'            
        ]);

.... code to get data ....

return new Response(200, $headers, $returndata);
```

Comment: `Status Code: 500` – so your attempt to respond with a status code 200 plus CORS headers, obviously did not work. So go and figure out what caused the 500 here to begin with, start by checking relevant error logs.

Comment: And FYI, the OPTIONS request should of course not be answered by sending _data_.

Comment: Yeh the returning data on the OPTIONS was one issue. From the console I can see I had two CORS issues and not sending data on the OPTIONS was fixed with the below using `if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
  $headers = array_merge($headers, [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '3600'   
        ]);
 return new Response(200, $headers, '');
 }`

Comment: I cannot find any decent logs in google cloud console or on the cloud functions in the firebase console, however the CORS is now saying
 
 referer: http://localhost:4200
 response-encoder: application/xml
 Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

Comment: The API connects to the external application via CURL so I attempted to set these headers as well as even though the referer is my localhost I think its the cloud function calling the external application which is giving me the issue. 
 
 `curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/moca-xml","Response-Encoder:application/xml", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Response-Encoder, Response-Type"));`

Comment: The issue was actually with my Angular code when making the call to the API. Certain headers are not allowed on the google cloud function i.e. removed request type and response encoder (meaning the header was just content type) which allowed the call to go through

Answer (score -1):

Firstly the angular app calling the google cloud PHP function was not allowed certain headers and in the end my header was just

```
private headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
```

Then in the google cloud PHP function, the OPTIONS request has to be handled by returning 200 or 204 as well as setting the headers on the response

```
 $headers = ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'];
 if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
     $headers = array_merge($headers, [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '3600'          
        ]);
    return new Response(200, $headers, '');
 } else {
     $headers = array_merge($headers, [
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Origin, Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '1000', 
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'    
            ]);
 }
```